# How to set and get TextField value using as props of functional component in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am totally new to react, I have sign up form which have 5 five input fields.

I created one functional component for TextField

**MyTextField.js**

```
function MyTextField(props) {
    return (
        <TextField 
            label={props.label} 
            name={props.name}
            placeholder={props.placeholder} 
            type={props.type}
            onChange={props.handleOnChange}
            value={props.value}
        ></TextField>
    )
}
export default MyTextField
```

**Signup.js**

```
function SignUp() {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    function FunConfirmPassword(event) {
        setValue = event.target.value //this function is calling, if I comment this line
        console.log('FunConfirmPassword called - password value = '+ value)
    }
    return (
        <MyTextField type="text"  label="Firstname" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter Firstname"></MyTextField>
        <MyTextField type="text"  label="Lastname" name="Lastname" placeholder="Enter Lastname"></MyTextField>
        <MyTextField type="text"  label="emailID" name="emailID" placeholder="Enter emailID"></MyTextField>
        <MyTextField type="password"  label="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"></MyTextField>

        <MyTextField handleOnChange={FunConfirmPassword}  type="password"  label="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Enter confirmpassword"></MyTextField>

    )
}
```

I am trying to learn how to set the value of TextField and get the value of same textfield.

At the same time, it must be re-usable function

Comment: Is the TextField a TextInput ?

Comment: The naming of `FunConfirmPassword` is really bad, in JS, do not use capital first letter if it's not for naming a class, instead use `camelCase`.

Comment: @Dimitrikopriwa I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've prepared a codepen example for you, where you can see how this works.

https://codepen.io/dns_nx/pen/BaxjdKd

Basically, you set a property to the child component, in which you define the function which is being executed, when called by the child (see property `onChange`).
To set the value in the `MyTextField` component, you just have to pass the current value of the variable in `SignUp` to your `MyTextField` component (see property `value`):

```
function SignUp(props) {
   const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');      

   ...
   <MyTextField 
       type="text"  
       label="Firstname" 
       name="firstName" 
       placeholder="Enter Firstname"
       value={firstName}
       onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value}
   />
   ...
}
```

Then you need to call the function where you need it in your child component (i.e. `onChange` event) to pass the new value to the parent component (`SignUp`). The value is set by the property `value`:

```
function MyTextField(props) {
   ...
    <TextField 
        ...
        value={props.value}
        onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event)}
        ...
    ></TextField>
}
```

This is the way to pass values from child components to parent components.

But as larger your application gets, it makes it hard to handle. Therefore I would recommend you to use a state management library like Redux (react-redux).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux

and use this with the toolkit package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reduxjs/toolkit

Comment: How will I re-use the useState for remaining `MyTextField` of `LastName, emaillID,password, confirmPassword`. Instead of creating multiple useState for each input field

Comment: That is up to you. You don't have to use separate `useState` variables for each field. You can also define an object variable like `const [signUpValues, setSignUpValues] = useState({ firstName: '', lastName: '', ...});` Then you can pass down the suitable property of the object to the different `MyTextFields` components. Of course, then you need to modify the updating of the property as well. But that is up to you, how you want to handle this.

Comment: thanks, it works. I really appreciate your time and effort. I go through this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3lL8oyev9w&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwisvxhZ135pogtX7_Oe3Q3A&index=4) regarding how to use useState with object.

Answer (score 2):

> how to set the value of TextField

In your code, the `<TextField>` gets its value from a prop:

```
value={props.value}
```

So to supply that value, pass it as that prop:

```
<MyTextField value={value} ...
```

> and get the value of same textfield

That you're already doing here:

```
<MyTextField handleOnChange={FunConfirmPassword} ...
```

However, you have a mistake in your handler function here:

```
setValue = event.target.value
```

`setValue` is a *function*.  This should be:

```
setValue(event.target.value);
```

Additionally, the `console.log` statement immediately following it won't [print what you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/328193).  React state updates are asynchronous and batched.  Either log `event.target.value` instead, or use a `useEffect` to respond to the updated `value` value and log it there.  (Or don't log it to the console at all, it's not really necessary.)

Comment: yes, you are correct, it works with this `setValue(event.target.value);`. as you said. In the console log, it doesn't print updated value.  I will check on how to update using useEffect. thanks